# SassC error - it doesn't matter what I change, I still get an Invalid CSS message

Tags: css, ruby, sass, ruby-on-rails-5, bulma

I've gone through pages of answers and I'm still stumped so here goes:

I'm trying to precompile my Rails app and always get met with a slight variation of this message:

```
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Invalid CSS after "...25rem 0}li:not(": expected selector, was 
 "'.dropdown-menu li'"
    on line 6:36279 of stdin
>> in-bottom:.5rem}li{margin:.25rem 0}li:not('.dropdown-menu li'):last-child{ma
   ------------------------------------------^
   stdin:6
```

I've looked at the CSS in question, and it's fine (no syntax errors, pages render perfectly in the local environment etc). I thought it was a framework issue so I switched from Bulma to another CSSf framework, and I still have the same problem.

Any time I have made a modification (eg removed the selector in its entrirety, the precompile brings up the same problem.  Please does anybody know why I'm getting hit with this error?

Comment: Just a guess but looks like you have some single quotes in the sass `'.dropdown-menu li'` and  `li:not('.dropdown-menu li')`.  Have you confirmed no stray quotes in there?

Comment: yes, ended up using another version of the `CSS file and moving it into application.css, where it worked.